# Pipe Command Output into Awk

Tags: awk, pipe, cat

I want to pipe the output of a command into awk. I want to add that number to every row of a new column in an existing .txt file.  The new column should be at the end, and won't necessarily be column 2.

$command 1

```
4512438
```

$ input.txt

```
A
B
C
D
```

$ desired_ouput.txt

```
A   4512438
B   4512438
C   4512438
D   4512438
```

I think I need to do something along the lines of the following.  I'm not sure how to designate that the pipe goes into the new column - this awk command will simply add integers to the column.

$ command1 | awk -F, '{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, input.txt > desired_ouput.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you really want to pipe the value to awk.  Instead, you want to pass it as a parameter.  You could read it from the pipe with something like:

```
cmd1 | awk 'NR==FNR{a=$0} NR!=FNR{print $0,a}' - input.txt
```

but it seems much more natural to do:

```
awk '{print $0,a}' a="$(cmd1)" input.txt
```

Comment: Wonderful - this worked!  Somewhat surprised that your second option worked.  For future reference, would this also work for a command that isn't in bash?  For instance, if I needed to call a script using sh script.sh?

Comment: Do you mean if `cmd1` is something like `sh script.sh`?  Yes, it will work for that.